# Определить с заданной точностью сумму членов бесконечного степенного ряда:

Tags: c++, ряды

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/***************************************************************************************
*                       О С Н О В Н А Я  П Р О Г Р А М М А                              *
***************************************************************************************/

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); //Объявление русского языка
    float Znam; //Объявление знаменателя
    float Sum; //Объявление суммы
    int i; //Объявление счетчика просуммированных элементов
    const float Tsum = 0.75;
    float Eps; //Объявление заданной точности
    float Diff; //Объявление разницы
    cout << "Введите Eps = ";
    cin >> Eps; //Ввод заданной точности
    cout << Eps << endl; //Эхо печать
    if (Eps > 0 && Eps < Tsum) //Входной контроль
    { 
        //Инициализация переменных
        Sum = 0.5;
        i = 1;
        Diff = Tsum - Sum; //Вычисление разницы
        //Подсчет суммы ряда
        while (Diff > Eps) //Основной цикл
        {
            Znam = ( (i) * (i + 1)); //Вычисление знаменателя
            Sum = Sum + (1 / Znam); //Вычисление суммы
            i = i + 1; //Обновление суммы
            Diff = Tsum - Sum; //Подсчет новой разницы
        }//while
        cout << "Количество просуммированных элементов = " << i - 2 << endl; //Вывод количества элементов
        cout << "Получившаяся сумма = " << Sum << endl; //Вывод суммы
        cout << "разница между суммой и точным значением = " << Diff << endl; //Вывод разницы суммы и точного значения
    } //If
    else
    {
        cout << "Eps должно быть в пределе от 0 до 0.75 \n"; //Вывод сообщения об ошибке
    }
    return 0;
}//Main


/***************************************************************************************
*                 К О Н Е Ц  О С Н О В Н О Й  П Р О Г Р А М М Ы                        *
***************************************************************************************/
```

у меня ответ один и тот же выходит

Comment: Интересно, а какой, собственно, ряд надо посчитать **в задании**? Как можно отвечать, не зная вопроса? По коду? Но ведь код у вас **нерабочий** (иначе бы вы не спрашивали), так что из него нельзя исходить, пытаясь восстановить задание...

Answer (score 0):

```
   while (Diff > Eps) //Основной цикл
    {
        Znam = i * (i + 1); //Вычисление знаменателя
        Diff = 1.0 / Znam;
        Sum = Sum + Diff; //Вычисление суммы
        i = i + 1; //Обновление суммы
    }//while
```

Что это за TSum у вас?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас цикл делает только одну итерацию. Вы сумму инициализировали почему-то значением 0,5. И на первой итерации добавляете к ней ещё 0,5. И всё - разница становится отрицательной и цикл завершается.

```
        Sum = 0.5;  // Почему? По-идее должно быть 0
        i = 1;
        Diff = Tsum - Sum; //Вычисление разницы
        
        while (Diff > Eps) //Основной цикл
        {
            Znam = ( (i) * (i + 1)); // на первой итерации 2
            Sum = Sum + (1 / Znam); // на первой итерации 0.5 + 0.5
            i = i + 1; //Обновление суммы
            Diff = Tsum - Sum; //Подсчет новой разницы -0,25 и выход из цикла
        }//while
```

Просто проинициализируйте переменную `Sum` нулем.